# Set environment variable inside a podman's container by shell script

Tags: podman, almalinux

Usign podman container with AlmaLinux on board.

I need to setup a set of environment variable **after** starting the container. So I put into the container a script `setenv.sh` with contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
export MYVAR=value
echo $MYVAR
```

Now I am running the container:

```
$ podman run --rm -it -init almatest bash
% /opt/myapp/bin/setenv.sh
value
% echo $MYVAR

% env | grep MYVAR
%
```

Where is my variable? What is going on?

Edit: Executing the script with `.` or `source` does prevent the environment variables from disappearing. Ok, I gues that answers my original question.

I know about the `-env` for the podman, but cannot use it - the container is a test environment for the production which would not have a podman. I need to do all setups from inside the container.

Comment: the same would happen if you would do it locally. You cannot export environment variable by executing the script. You need to source it. `source /opt/myapp/bin/setenv.sh` or `. /opt/myapp/bin/setenv.sh` for better compat.

Comment: What is the actual target environment? Most container orchestration systems have a way to set container environment variables from outside the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know where I went wrong.

The `setup.sh` is a script which is supposed to be run first. And I thought about it, like it is a `.bashrc`, so `export` in the `setup.sh` should work as in `.bashrc`. And that was the source of my mistake.

The intended role of the script is not a real one.

So the call of `setup.sh` should be done by `source` command.